# Как русифицировать Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: русификация, ide, eclipse

Как мне русифицировать Eclipse Indigo 32bit. Ведь сложновато мне - идет Eng. Напишите мне пошаговую инструкцию. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что разработчик в любом случае должен знать английский, так как по роду деятельности в любом случае приходится сталкиваться с англоязычной документацией. Да и терминология вся на английском, не говоря уже о семантике в идентификаторах (транслит не прокатит, конвенция). Потому и необходимости в переводе в принципе нет. Так что лучше выучить язык, по крайней мере терминологию сначала

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором (Артем Быков) - сам никогда не использую переведенные IDE. Тем не менее ответ на вопрос топикстартера есть.

[Фтыкать здесь](http://ddark008.ru/eclipce/)